# Recycler View is Overriding the ToolbarMenu

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, toolbar

[image: Emulator Pic]

this is my Xml code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_standalone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--    Navigation View Describe here input are header and toolbar-->
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:itemIconTint="#8C000000"
            app:itemTextColor="#E6000000"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu_items_grouped">

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!--recycler view add here-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here Recycler View is coming above the toolbar.
Toolbar is not showing in the Emulator Screen.
Recycler view is working perfectly but toolbar and its menu are not showing.
Please let me correct layout to resolve this issue.
please let me know what are the change required to do in XML file.

Comment: Move the `<RecyclerView>` into the `<LinearLayout>`, after the `<include>`, and get rid of the outer `ConstraintLayout` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

your RecyclerView have

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

it make baseline from parent. So change this.

```
<!--recycler view add here-->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/drawerLayout"   //change this
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Not working, Recycler View item are not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

S T ansewer is right, just inverted. Try this:

Instead of `bottomToTop` should be 'topToBottom`, since you want to put the recyclerview top close to drawers bottom.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/drawerLayout"   //change this
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me :-

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_standalone" />

            <!--recycler view add here-->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```